# Variable 'x' is uninitialized when used here

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
   int *x;
   *x = 100;
   printf("\n *x = %d \n &x = %p \n sizeof(x) = %lu \n",
          *x,(void*)x,sizeof(x));
   return 0;
  }
```

I think i missed something in this program, can anyone help me ?

Comment: what is the value of x supposed to be?  What x is pointing to gets assigned to 100, but what is x pointing to?

Comment: Your pointer points nowhere, you have to malloc and only then assign some value to the address pointed by x

Comment: `int *x = malloc(sizeof(int)); *x = 100;...`

Comment: @sergeyrar its not necessary to malloc, either stack or data assignments would also work.  malloc is required for heap though.

Comment: When you define `int *x;`, the actual value of `x`, which is supposed to be an address of an `int` variable, is uninitialized. `*x = 100;` means "set the value at the memory location contained in `x` to 100". However because you never did anything like `int y; x = &y`, the memory location x is pointing to is some random value.

Comment: Yes this is just an option

Comment: Curious, why use `"%lu"` with `sizeof(x)` vs. using `"%u"` or `"%zu"`?

Comment: @sergeyrar, it is indeed an option, but you said _"you have to"_ - that is the part that is wrong in you advice.  Moreover for a single integer, as a solution it has little merit.

Comment: @RandomDavis  That is a much clearer and informative answer than the code-fragment-only answers currently posted.  You really should have posted an answer rather then a comment.

Comment: @Clifford thanks, I re-posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should init `x` like

```
int a;
int* x = &a;
*x = 100; // a = 100
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define `int *x;`, the actual *value* of `x`, which is supposed to be the address of an `int` variable, is uninitialized because you haven't assigned any value to it yet. `*x = 100;` means "set the value at the memory location contained in `x` to 100". However because you never set the value of `x`, for example by doing something like `int y; x = &y`, the memory location that `x` is pointing to is some random value.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
   int y = 0;
   //int *x;
   int *x = &y; //Need to assign x an address to point to, or else its stack garbage and could be anywhere...
   *x = 100;
   printf("\n *x = %d \n &x = %p \n sizeof(x) = %lu \n",
          *x,(void*)x,sizeof(x));
   return 0;
  }
```

Comment: @Osiris Thanks correct.  I copy/pasted his original code with a solution to his original problem, but he has more than one.

Comment: Thank you, I am completely new to programming and did not know it should be assigned !